# Combined probability of drawing king after ace

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I'm studying for a math test and I found an interesting question:
Assume someone is drawing cards from 32-card deck. How likely is he to get a pair of king and ace after each other. He isn't returning the cards back.

I wanted to solve this by $\frac{4}{32} * \frac{4}{31}$ which would result in $\frac{1}{62}$. But these are questions which already pre-solved and the expected answer should be $\frac{1}{14384}$

How should I approach this?

Comment: How many kings and aces are there in this $32$-card deck?

Comment: Based on the result $\frac{1}{14384} = \frac{60}{32\cdot31\cdot30\cdot29}$, I expect they want to find the probability of a pair of kings, followed by a pair of aces, maybe?

Comment: There should be 4 kings and 4 aces in the deck (4 colors, numbering starts from 7: i.e. 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A), and yes, the tasks ask for a chance of picking a pair: king followed by an ace

Comment: Although I don't understand how did you get the $\frac{60}{32*31*30*29}$ @BrianTung

Comment: Can you quote the exact question?

Comment: Well it's kind of hard since it's in my native language, not english, I did my best to transalte it @MishaLavrov

Comment: You could quote the question in your native language, though I agree that it's less likely to clarify things that way.

Comment: Well if you insist: "Postupne vyberáme dve karty z 32 kariet (vybrenú kartu späť nevraciame). Aká je šanca, že vyberieme dvojicu: kráľ-eso"
Vaguely translated as: "Gradually, we select two cards from 32 cards (we do not return the selected card). What is the chance that we will choose a pair: king-ace"
It's in Slovak @MishaLavrov

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any other way to read that other than how you've interpreted it. (I don't know Slovak, but I do know Russian.) It may also be a mistake in the answer key.

Comment: for me it looks now like the question is: what is the probability of drawing a king and an ace (no matter in which order) and the answer would be 8/32 times 4/31 = 1/31. So I tend to agree with Misha, that there is a mistake in the proposed answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach was (almost) correct, the first draw must be a king and you have 4 out of 32 possibilities, the second must be again a king, but there are only 3 left so you have 3 out of 31. As Brian Tung noticed $\frac{1}{14384}$ = $\frac{60}{32 \cdot 31 \cdot 30 \cdot 29}$ which means that you probably draw 4 cards. If the third card shall be an ace you would have 4 out of 30 and for another ace you would have 3 out of 29. In total the probability would be $\frac{144}{14384}$ (144 = 4 x 3 x 4 x 3). I don't see a simple question where the answer would be $\frac{60}{14384}$ because 60 = 5 x 12, which means at some point you should have the choice of 5 cards!? Really strange ...